# Vlookup + Match issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with the formula below.

```
=VLOOKUP(B$22,Scenarios.New!$A$1:$M$211,MATCH(Output!$A27,Scenarios.New!$A$1:$M$1,0),FALSE)
```

Take a look at the image
[image]

This is basically doing one thing. Find the Action No. that is in the sheet "Scenario.New" of the Scenario ID 1017. It is working fine, as it returns 1,so formula is working, but sometimes I have 2 actions.

[image]

[image]

As you see. my formula will only look at the first Scend ID and will ignore the other one as is already found the first one. What I want to do is add a piece in the code that says Action No. = 1 or 2. Because based on the action No. some other fields will change too. Any ideas to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I think that a VBA would best fit your needs. Where [AutofIlter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) would be your friend

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

first, i'm doubt with your question. second, your tabel is horisontal but you use **VLOOKUP**? or im wrong to undertand this?

but let me help you,i think you should try this,

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phkL0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXHab.png)

```
=HLOOKUP(A5;Sheet1!$A$4:$G$5;2;FALSE)
```

take number 1 or 2 from table. but, if your table have double value be reference like image, **HLOOKUP** return first reference.